# Chrome inline extension installation error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am getting following error when i try to install Chrome extension:

extensions::webstore:34 Uncaught Chrome Web Store installations can only be started by the top frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is pretty self-explanatory.

The code you're using to initiate `chrome.webstore.install()` is running in a document that's not the top one (i.e. is an `iframe` inside another document).

This is not allowed. It has to be a top document for inline installation to start.

Comment: Yes that fixed but now I am getting this error:  A Chrome Web Store installation is already pending.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: yes, Iframe was the issue in my case.

Comment: I have added this outside of Iframe now working fine.

Comment: I am not using iFrame but getting the same issue.

Comment: Confirmed, I am calling it from top document.